# Are my questions really this bad?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just noticed this "recommended" badge in my profile and I'm rather confused.

[image]

I have $20$ out of the $5$ needed questions for this badge, but apparently they are "poor" questions so they don't actually count towards the count? Kinda bummed to see that, I've been quite diligent and working hard to make my questions as best I can.

Comment: FYI, see [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259), and the Meta FAQ [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399). Also, somewhat related is [Misleading description of new Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234956).

Comment: How many questions have you asked and later deleted?

Comment: I have deleted none of my questions

Comment: (How is a "positive question record calculated?")[https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated]  Do you perhaps have a few old downvoted, closed, and deleted questions? It would only take 5 to give you a negative question record with 18 positive questions and 2 closed ones.

Edit: I see you haven't deleted any questions. Its worth noting that unanswered downvoted questions will eventually be deleted automatically. Maybe this is the cause? I don't have enough reputation to check. Barring these scenarios this is baffling.

Answer (score 21):

I am confused as well. I read the criteria described in [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259), and as far as I can tell, Clyde has met the criteria.

Here are seven questions asked by Clyde. For each question, Clyde asked no other questions that day. Each is well-received, because each has a positive score, and is neither deleted nor closed. Finally, Clyde's question record should be impeccable, since they have asked $38$ questions, and have no negative questions, and only two closed questions.

Since seven > five, shouldn't this qualify?

[Does there exist such a Riemann integrable function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4428583/does-there-exist-such-a-riemann-integrable-function)
[Power series expansion of $\arctan (x)$ centered at $x=0$ extends to $x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555473/power-series-expansion-of-arctan-x-centered-at-x-0-extends-to-x-1)

[Prove $f(r, \theta) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571663/prove-fr-theta-cos-theta-sin-theta-is-continuous)

[Is $C([0,1])$ complete if $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$ is the inner product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592468/is-c0-1-complete-if-int-01-fxgxdx-is-the-inner-product)

[If $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597451/if-f-n-converges-pointwise-to-f-then-f-is-uniformly-continuous)

[Find intersection points of $x^2 - 3xy+ 2y^2 - x + 1 = 0$ and $y = \alpha x + \beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633708/find-intersection-points-of-x2-3xy-2y2-x-1-0-and-y-alpha-x-b)

[What is the difference between an $FG$-module and a group algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639371/what-is-the-difference-between-an-fg-module-and-a-group-algebra)

[In $\triangle ABC$, $DE$ parallel to $BC$, $F$ midpoint of $DE$, $AF$ meets $BC$ at $G$. Prove $G$ is the midpoint of $BC$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640757/in-triangle-abc-de-parallel-to-bc-f-midpoint-of-de-af-meets-bc)