# What's wrong with my 'Curious' badge?

Tags: support, bug, badges, badge-tracking

A partial screenshot of my MSE profile is as follows:

[image]

As one can see, I have already fulfilled the threshold to be awarded the 'Curious' badge, but it was never awarded to me. What's going on? Please share your knowledge and possible fixes. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how the alleged duplicate answers this question. Curiouser and curiouser....

Comment: @GerryMyerson - The correct duplicate post is in the Related list: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23431/why-was-the-curious-badge-badge-not-being-awarded

Comment: Seems like this is a recurring issue: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35512/are-my-questions-really-this-bad